# Assumed, I hash the next bitcoin block. Whom do I tell if it's decentralized?

Tags: mining-pools, hash, decentralization

The bitcoin network is decentralized, right?

Assumed, I do hash a little bit and get a hash that starts with 20 Zeros..

What do I do than? I need to send the block to someone but who is that? It's decentralized... Do I send it to all the other miners?

Comment: Bitcoin’s open source software does that for you. There’s no need to do it manually. If you insist on it though, i’d recommend reading the p2p code from the [repo](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't tell a specific node on the network, but rather broadcast your block to the entire network.  You essentially scream it from the rooftop.

If it's valid, it will be in the best interest of everyone to recognize your block and start mining on top of it.

Comment: "You essentially scream it from the rooftop" Ok, but how exactly? That's what I don't understand.

Comment: You are connected to multiple nodes.  You send it to all the nodes.

Comment: And they will send it on to everyone they are connected to.

Answer (score 2):

You broadcast it to all the nodes you are connected to (usually at least 6), and they broadcast it to all the nodes they are connected to and so on. In this way it propagates across the whole network.